# Postgresql / Hibernate - Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Recently I migrated my application from `Oracle` to `PostgreSql` (9.2.20). I used `org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType` for storing document contents (`bytes` property) in DB:

```
<hibernate-mapping >
  <class name="x.y.z.entities.DocumentDataEntity" table="ds_document_data">
    <id name="id" column="id_" type="java.lang.String">
      <generator class="uuid2"/>
    </id>
    <property name="bytes" column="BYTES_" type="org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

`bytes` property in `DocumentDataEntity` class:

```
private byte[] bytes;
```

It works fine in `Oracle` but in `PostgreSql`, loading `DocumentDataEntity` throws this exception:

```
18:54:57 ERROR [ds/root] i.a.w.c.d.e.ApplicationExceptionHandler -| Error occured in calling rest method! org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.open(LargeObjectManager.java:265)
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.open(LargeObjectManager.java:251)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.AbstractBlobClob.getLo(AbstractBlobClob.java:283)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.AbstractBlobClob.getBinaryStream(AbstractBlobClob.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.wrap(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:115)
    ... 163 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.wrap(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.wrap(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BlobTypeDescriptor$1.doExtract(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2790)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4019)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:997)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:73)
```

**Note:**

- I'm using `Spring` (4.3.8.RELEASE) and `Hibernate` (5.0.12.Final).
- I used `@Transactional` annotaion in `DocumentDataManager` bean's `load` method.
- Saving/Loading works fine in `Oracle`.

Comment: Did you any solution to this issue? Facing something similar